# How to delete a line above a bookmark in Word using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with various Bookmarks in it. Given specifications from a database, I loop through all of them and change the text of the range. In some cases I need to delete two lines above a bookmark. I believe this can be accomplished with a few lines of code, but I haven't been able to get anything to work. The closest I've gotten is the following:

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(1).Range.Sentences(1).Delete
```

In my project, I each bookmark range is only one line (one sentence). Since the two lines I want to delete are above the bookmark (and not in its range). How could I offset the `Sentences` member to allow me to do so?

Comment: Sendkey to move two lines up and then delete line?

Comment: As an alternative, are you in a position to bookmark the two lines you want to delete? Then you should be able to delete them by deleting the range of the bookmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub DeletePrevTwoSentences()
    Dim r As Word.Range

    Set r = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TheBookmark").Range
    Debug.Print r.start, r.end  ' Just for testing

    ' Move the start of r back two sentences
    r.MoveStart wdSentence, -2

    ' Move the end of r back one sentence
    ' Assumes the bookmark refers to an entire sentence that shouldn't get deleted
    ' Could also set end = start, then move end +2 sentences.
    r.MoveEnd wdSentence, -1
    Debug.Print r.start, r.end  ' Just for testing
    r.Delete
End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I didn't know about MoveStart and MoveEnd! Thanks for that! I did need to modify it a bit, the `r.MoveEnd wdSentence, -1` line is not needed, at least it wasn't in my case (The bookmark is placed on an empty line).